# Update custom field in User by email

Tags: wordpress

I have added a custom field for Users.
The value is set with
`update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wwp_aanwezigheid', $_POST['wwp_aanwezigheid'] );`
It works fine. I made it visible in the Users Table.

Idealy i would like to have the following setup:
I send a mail to a (or all) user(s). That mail should have a YES and a NO button in the body.
If they click on YES, the custom field *wwp_aanwezigheid* should be changed to "Aanwezig"
If they click on NO, the custom field *wwp_aanwezigheid* should be changed to "Absent"

How can i update custom user fields by mail. Is it even possible?
Do i compromize the security ?

Kind regards,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could do this directly from email. You have to get them on the website and do the magic there.

Send email like you normally would and create two links with arguments like:

```
website.com/landing?user_id=12&wwp_aanwezigheid=true
website.com/landing?user_id=12&wwp_aanwezigheid=false
```

Create a function in `function.php` that reads URL arguments and use function:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

After that just update the value

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wwp_aanwezigheid', $wwp_aanwezigheid );
```

For security purposes encrypt their ID!

Comment: Wow, well it seems to be more than my beginners programming skills can handle but i'll give it a go. Thanks for pointing me in the direction!